# How I can know a file source code in cpanel from inspect element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, web

I'm stuck when I want to edit my website, because I don't know which file I have to open and edit.

When I use "inspect element", it doesn't tell me the specific file that the styling came from. Usually it says something like "style.css:(line number)". But in my case, it just say "inline". I have to search on cpanel through every file on it, and I don't find a file that contains data which I want to edit.

Can you give me any idea to solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: Inline styles directly applied to the tag/element in html file. So you need to look in html file.

Answer (score 0):

Inline means that this style is defined in the html file. An example of inline style

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:100px; height:50px; color: blue;"></div>
```

You need to look in the HTML file that contains your element.
In general CSS can be added to HTML in 3 ways:

- **Inline** - by using the style attribute in HTML elements
- **Internal** - by using a `<style>` element in the  section
- **External** - by using an external CSS file

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Inline refers To style added in HTML elements . 
Check your html file find the element and check its attribute ✌

If elements doesn't have it , then  the css properties is implement by JavaScript  .